# Why am I getting a "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" error?

Tags: r

I'm currently working with a dataframe "dat." I'm trying to calculate a score using columns 69-88 (if there are values in any of those columns, then add them together and put the result in a new column called "score").

This is the code I have now:

```
dat$score <- 0
for (num in 69:88){
  dat$score[!is.na(dat[,num])] <- dat$score+dat[,num]
}
```

This gives me a column where some rows show the correct score, but other rows are returning "NA". I also have 20 warnings messages that look like so:

> 1: In dat$score[!is.na(dat[, num])] <- dat$score +  ... :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Why is my code working for some rows and not for others, and why am I getting this error?

Comment: please share your `dat` dataframe, or at least part of it, with `dput(head(dat))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the `rowSums()`function? You just have to add the argument `na.rm=TRUE`.
A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(score=rowSums(across(69:88), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Or with `base R`

```
dat$score<-rowSums(dat[, 69:88], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `apply`. its usually quicker than for

```
dat$score <- apply(dat[,69:88], 1, sum, na.rm = T)
```